# Twitter bootsrap icon not showing on Calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement a datetimepicker on a web page using [this example](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I am using Bootstrap 3.

This example uses Twitter bootstrap 2 so I had to change some of the classes following Bootstrap 2 - 3 migration guide.

My problem is when I click on the calender icon it shows up successfully however the time icon that should be embedded at the bottom of the calender does not show.

Does anyone know why that is?

```
  <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
      <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar glyphicon-time">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a link or a fiddle would help

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but make sure in your bootstrap css assets that you have the correct URL to your glyphicons

Answer (score 0):

The new way of doing that in Bootstrap 3 is using class 'input-group' instead of 'input-append'. You also have to put the class 'form-control' in your input.

```
<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar glyphicon-time"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

You can check this exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezrv9/3/
You also can have more information here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?